# Reading <p> tag's text in a managed bean

Tags: java, html, jsf, facelets, managed-bean

Wel i guess the header sums it up, i have a managed bean linked to a `Facelets` page, i want to read text from normal `html <p>` element into the managed bean or send it to it.

I have this

tag dynamicly created with a JavaScript, so thats why I can't use JSF elements.

example

```
<p> text text </p>
```

Is it possible ? I need it because ia have alot of normal `Html` elements that I want to use
the text in (normal means not a facelets or any java tag).

Edit: now i used the javascript method and the  but it keeps returning null in the bean side, like the values are not set at all.

[Backing Bean not getting values sent by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182875/backing-bean-not-getting-values-sent-by-javascript/11183047#comment14675075_11183047) this thread now has the problem with all its data.

Comment: Instead of creating dynamic tags, can't you set just dynamic text for predefined h:outputText / h:inputHidden ? Is there any other problem with that ?

Comment: yes because its an application that depends on javascript, so i have to use the normal html tags

Comment: You can put a JSF component to enclose the `<p>`s e.g. a `Panel` or `Fragment`  and bind these components to backing bean property and parse the contents in backing bean.

Comment: that could work but would take lots of programming, but isn't there a way get the html data from the backing bean directly ?

Comment: The best thing would be to pass that text into a `<h:inputHidden>` in the "onclick" javascript method of your commandButton/commandLink, in that way your JSF managed bean could take the text value. You can do it using pure JavaScript methods, like innerHTML, but that's another matter

Comment: would you please explain more ? so i could get the text from the dynamicly created <p> element and put it inputHidden ? knowing that its dynamicly created <p> means that its value is not determined until some function occurs after the page is loaded.

Comment: @Developer106 so what? The important matter is the UIComponent values when the `action` method is called (and if they are valid values). Here is a [Javascript InnerHTML](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php) code sample. You can change/get the inner HTML of any component, once you get the value (doesn't matter if that text is dynamically created) you should set it into a <h:inputHidden /> (remember that this hidden should be inside the <h:form>), then the action will be performed and the inputHidden value will be available in your server side.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza your solution is a poor tip for someone using Facelets. If JavaScript is disabled, then the page will behave inconsistently.

Comment: and what do you suggest ? @thejartender

Comment: @thejartender "tag dynamicly created with a JavaScript, so thats why I can't use JSF elements" if JavaScript is disabled then the page won't work either :). I would like to see your answer to this problem.

Comment: i tried the method of using the javascript and the input hidden and it keeps returning null in the backing bean in the values it is supposed to set

Comment: @Developer106 edit your post and add what have you tried to see how we can help you.