# Backing Bean not getting values sent by javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, facelets, managed-bean

I have three drop down lists whose values are been copied to `<h:inputHidden>` components by the following JavaScript function:

```
function getBirthDate() {
    var months = document.getElementById("months")
    var hidden1 =  document.getElementById("formsignup:monthField");
    hidden1.value = months.options[months.selectedIndex].text;
    var days = document.getElementById("days");
    var hidden2 = document.getElementById("formsignup:dayField");
    hidden2.value = days.options[days.selectedIndex].value;
    var years = document.getElementById("years");
    var hidden3 = document.getElementById("formsignup:yearField");
    hidden3.value = years.options[years.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Here are the three `<h:inputHidden>` components:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{signupBean.month}" id="monthField"/>
<h:inputHidden value="#{signupBean.day}" id="dayField"/>
<h:inputHidden value="#{signupBean.year}" id="yearField"/>
```

This is the command button that is supposed to invoke the function that copies the values to the inputs and then submits them to the backing bean.

```
<h:commandButton image="images/images/signup1.png" 
     styleClass="joinnow" 
     id="joinus" action="#{signupBean.save}"
     onclick="getBirthDate()" />
```

But they arrive as `null` in the backing bean. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Edit: jQuery freezes when I try to select elements from JSF components. Is there a problem with the IDs of the elements?

Edit: below is a screenshot of the variables sent along with the HTTP request which proves that the values are properly been sent. What would be the problem with the bean?

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that the right changed values are been sent to the server? Check the HTTP traffic in your webbrowser's developer toolset.

Comment: Make sure that your `<h:inputHidden>`s are inside your `<h:form>` and your `getBirthDate` method works, you can test each pass using `console.log()` in Firefox (using firebug) or Chrome (using the Chrome console by pressing Ctrl + Shift + J).

Comment: About the IDs, JSF will change the ID of the components by the form <container>:<myId>, for example in `<h:form id="myForm"> <h:inputText id="myInputText" /> </h:form>` the id for "myInputText" will be "myForm:myInputText", if your JSF component is outside the form like `<h:inputText id="myInputText" /> <h:form id="myForm"> <!-- some content here... --> </h:form>` the the "myInputText" id will be "myInputText" because isn't inside a container.

Comment: thanks luiggi for the answer, but i realize that ofcourse and thats why am using this kind of id in tha javascript.

Answer (score 0):

can you check the scope of your bean and if it is getting reintialized during your submit.. in that case the hidden fields gets its initial values no matter if the values are being sent from client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the object is present or not by using **alert** statement. Example

```
function getBirthDate() {
var months = document.getElementById("months")
var hidden1 =  document.getElementById("formsignup:monthField");
alert(months);alert(months.value);
alert(hidden1);alert(hidden1.value);
```

If the Object value is null the Id is you given to get the element is not proper.. also check the value you are getting from the object.. I think it may help